# Firestore write limit to collection with composite index

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Firestore usage limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas)

> Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain
>   sequential values in an indexed field

How does this relate to composite indexes? Suppose I have an index on a field **occasionId**(string) and a field **date**(timestamp) for a collection **events**. Would > 500 document creations in a second all with the current server timestamp as their **date** value cause the limit to be hit or only if they all had the same occasionId value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you will still hit the limit since the per field default index of `date` field is sequential and can not be removed in the beta version.

For more details you can see the discussion on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/gA05mhSiYIo/r9HpaXPuAwAJ) and on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46570759/10553701).