# Does single-field index limitation applies to compound indexes too?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Cloud Firestore for my project and stumbled in this limitation:

> Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain sequential values in an indexed field: 500 per second

I understand the limitation based on this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567076/a-limit-clarification-for-the-new-firestore)
But if I disabled auto single-field indexes in firebase console, and only use this fields in compound indexes, this limitation still continues? I mean, does this single-field index limitation extends to compound indexes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation applies to writes to collections that have indexes. It applies equally to single-field and to compound indexes.

It's easiest to think of this as writing to a set of files, where you can write to each file about 500 times per second. Entries in an index that are close to each other (e.g. sequential) are written to the same 'file', so you can only write about 500 items close to each other in any index per second.

Comment: Thanks Frank!
So if I have a collection with high rate writes, maybe is it better to move that collection to a subcollection?

Comment: To a single subcollection won't make a difference. But sharding the same documents over multiple subcollections indeed will likely increase write throughput.